# Apache Nutch nowhere to be found

Tags: apache, nutch

I'm looking for Nutch installation files but no server has them, they're all empty.

http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/nutch/

Has it been moved or just retired??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i encountered the same problem earlier today. finally one of the mirrors had the actual package. just keep clicking! :-P

Comment: Its been like that for 3 days at least :(

Comment: yeah and still counting. pretty strange. i went to download Nutch2 package on another machine and none of the mirrors actually contain the package.

Comment: Used curl to loop though all the mirrors till it found one http://www.sai.msu.su/apache/nutch/2.2.1/

Answer (score 0):

all hail Lord Google...found the most recent release in the 'archives'.

http://archive.apache.org/dist/nutch/2.2.1/

Answer (score 0):

Just an update Nutch 2.3.1 is the latest version
http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/nutch/2.3.1/apache-nutch-2.3.1-src.tar.gz